# How to include an js and jsp files in .component.html page of angular 9

Tags: angular

I have zero knowledge on angular. I know javascript.
I got assigned to a task to work on angular 9. I have two files test.jsp and test_js.jsp and I have a simulator.component.html and simulator.component.ts files.
I need to bind/include those two files to that html page so that when I choose this html page it has to display the js/jsp files.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to *bind* js files to html files in Angular but the correct way would be to rewrite your js files in typescript and include them in your simulator.component.ts file. Is it possible for you to share your code? All 3 of them.

Comment: Does it help? https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/eigzry/jsp_and_angular_8/fcq4nif/